# Understanding the Quantum Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I have a question about the Quantum Fourier Transform. I would like to understand it because I have a re-take for an exam. I have studied the provided / recommended literature extensively. Unfortunately, studying the literature did not provided me a good understanding of this subject. I hope that some one could provide me some help. Let me first provide the Quantum Fourier Transform:
\begin{align}
F_{M} | k \rangle &=   \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}} \sum_{j = 0}^{2^{m}-1} e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{2^m}  jk } | j \rangle= 
\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^m}} \bigotimes(|0\rangle + e^{2\pi i k / 2^{l}} |1\rangle)  
\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^m}} (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \otimes(|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m-1}k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \dots (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{1}k_{2} \dots k_{m}} | 1 \rangle)   
\end{align}
I am able to understand the following part:
\begin{align}
F_{M}| k \rangle &=   \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}} \sum_{j = 0}^{2^{m}-1} e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{2^m}  jk }| j \rangle
\end{align}
I am also able to understand the second part:
\begin{align}
 &=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^m}} (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \cdot (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m-1}k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \dots (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{1}k_{2} \dots k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) 
\end{align}
I get stuck at the third part. I do understand that applying a Walsh-Hadamard transform on a set of bits produces the outcome:
\begin{align}
H^{\bigotimes n}|y\rangle_{n} &= \sum_{x = 0}^{2^n-1} (-1)^{x\cdot y }|y\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{m}}}
(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) \dots (|0\rangle + |1\rangle) 
\end{align}
In order to get a better understanding of the Quantum Fourier Transform, I would like to know why do I get the following?
\begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^m}} (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \cdot (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m-1}k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \dots (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{1}k_{2} \dots k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) 
\end{align}
I am aware of that $0.k_{1}k_{2} \dots k_{m}$ is a fraction in binary representation. What confuses me is why is this so important? What does that binary representation plays such a big role? I would like to note that an example on Wikipedia also has a fractional representation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform#Example

Finally, to get an understanding I wrote on a sheet of a paper a specific case where $M = 2^3 =8$ then $m = 3$. Again I get the binary fractional part. From that I am unable to work further.

Comment: What does the "$\cdot$" product indicate? Based on context I would've expected $\otimes$ instead.

Comment: If you mean with the following:
\begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^m}} (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \cdot (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{m-1}k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) \dots (|0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i 0.k_{1}k_{2} \dots k_{m}} | 1 \rangle) 
\end{align}
then $\bigotimes$ could also be used instead.

Comment: @Clifford I think you mean to write $F_{M} | k \rangle =   \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}} \sum_{j = 0}^{M-1} e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{M}  jk } | j \rangle $?